# Creating a UNIX default date time with same format as my API [ Angular 6 - TypeScript ]

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime, angular6

Thank you for reading and thank you for your help in advance.

I am trying to create a new Date time with the same format as my API call to retrieve data.

My goal here is to create a new default date then compare it with dates coming from my API call.

Date format coming from my API : Note this format cannot be changed.

```
2018-07-12T14:20:13.8434451Z
```

To create a new Date I do the following:

```
this.defaultdate= new Date();
```

Format displayed:

```
Thu Oct 04 2018 12:11:13 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Note that I have to keep this within my .ts file.

Is there a way to change the default date format to fit my API call format so I can compare both dates ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To compare both dates

```
new Date("2018-07-12T14:20:13.8434451Z").getTime() < this.defaultdate.getTime()
```

Comment: This does not work, the format is the same as new Date();  and also type becomes a string...I need it in Date format to compare them.

Comment: getTime() return a number, so that wont work either.

Comment: this.defaultdate is type of string in your example, and with getTime, it compares it with a number. incompatible type.

Comment: You can't use getTime() with a string, function does not exist with that type.

Comment: Both variables are dates. Perhaps my previous toJson() was confusing so I removed it.

Comment: It works, but my browser is screaming that getTime is not a function. Very weird. I can display both numbers in my console thought.

Comment: forgot the word new on new Date() perhaps?